# django comment form on post detailview

Tags: python, django

i am still learning django. trying to create a comment form in my blogdetail view.. i am following a tutorial from youtube..

```
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=An4hW4TjKhE&t=40s
```

this tutorial has form which takes users from django users .. but in my form i want user to enter his name ,email and content..
following this tutorial i made form model but i have no idea how to get data from my own html form by this..

i have reached to a stage where in admin i can add comments and display them in my html file but now i am getting an error..

```
             name 'post' is not defined
```

my files are..

forms.py

```
         from django import forms

         from.models import Comment

          class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
                class Meta:
                   model = Comment
                   fields = ('content', 'email', 'name' ,)
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
writer = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='my dept')
category =models.CharField(max_length=150)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
post   = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
Date  = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField (max_length = 150)
email = models.CharField (max_length = 150)
content = models.TextField ()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

views.py

```
def detailview(request, id=None):
blg =  get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)
comments = Comment.objects.filter( post=blg).order_by('-id')

if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None )
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        Comment.objects.create(post= post ,  content=content)
        comment_form.save()
else:
   comment_form = CommentForm()

context = {'blg': blg,
           'comments': comments,
           'comment_form' : comment_form,

           }

return render(request, 'blog/blogdetail.html', context)
```

blogdetail.html

```
        <div id="respond" class="clearfix">
                        <div class="title-box">
                            <h3>Leave a <strong>Comment</strong></h3>
                        </div><!-- end title-box -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- start Comment Form -->
                            <form class="clearfix" action="#" method="post" id="commentform">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <p class="comment-notes"><span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span> Required fields are marked <span class="required">*</span></p>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <label>Comment<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <textarea name="comment" cols="58" rows="7" tabindex="4" class="form-control" required >{{comment.content}}</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input name="author" id="author" value="" size="22" tabindex="1" class="form-control" type="text" required >{{comment.name}}</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input name="email" id="email" value="" size="22" tabindex="2" class="form-control" type="text" required >{{comment.email}}</div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit-button" tabindex="5" value="Submit" class="btn btn-shutter-out-horizontal  btn-lg">Submit Comment</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                            </form>
                            <!-- end Comment Form -->
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- #respond end -->
```

it actually looks like this

[![comment form][1]][1]

i want to post name email and comment from front end .. wasted almost 2 days without no success.. please help..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjDZ6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are passing the data manually from html rewrite this function

```
 if comment_form.is_valid():
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        name = request.POST.get('author', '')
        comment =Comment.objects.create(post= blg, email=email, name=name,  content=content)
        return redirect('posts-detail', pk=comment.id )<this can be how you like it>
```

what you are missing is getting the missing fields in html they are taken from name attribute in the input

Comment: hi i made few changes accordingly.. but now i am getting following error.. `null value in column "post_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (11, zasa, dfdfdf, sandeep, null).`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to remove post from my answer i just edited it, you can pass the post that you want to save it to, <blg>  so in the create function pass post=blg and it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
if comment_form.is_valid():
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    Comment.objects.create(post= blg ,  content=content) # YOU HAVE ADDED post= post even post variable you are not define
    comment_form.save()
```